# How to get rid of the blue line in character follow path animation?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, parent, path

[image]

The blue line makes the gap between the path and the character. So when I play it, the character walks in a huge circle. How do I get rid of the blue line so that it'll snap into the path?

Answer (score 1):

Select the character and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to reset its location. An object that has a *Follow Path* constraint will be as far from the curve start as it is far from the world center.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!